# Mozilla Thunderbird requests Master Password Twice?

Tags: thunderbird

Why Mozilla Thunderbird is asking `Master Password` twice for each session?
Some google results are saying it's because of `Lightning` addon but when I disable it and restart program there is no difference and it asks for Master Password twice again!

Answer (score -1):

In accordance with my experience, Lightning is not the only add-on which may make Thunderbird asking you for the master password more than once.
As you probably have found somewhere in the Internet, many users found in the "Master Password+" add-on a suitable way to workaround the issue by tuning some preferences.